# send and receive byte array form servlet to another servlet via ur

Tags: java, servlets

I have a byte array that is a Message digest. And i want send it to another appliction in same server via url.I don't want to convert it to string and pull back the array on the other end.

Can any one help me do this using servlet?

my code like bellow

Sendrequauset.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        byte[] encryptedUserName;               
        String username = request.getParameter("username");     
        RsaEncryption encrypt = new RsaEncryption();
        encryptedUserName     = encrypt.encryptClientMassage(username.getBytes(),pk,md);
        String url = "domain/server/GetRequset?username="+encryptedUserName+"";
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }

}
```

GetRequset.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //i want to get username to byte array from here.I try with request.getParameter("username") but i returns string


    }
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326555/transferring-file-contentbyte-array-from-one-serverservlet-to-another-server may help...though I am not quite sure....

Answer (score 1):

```
URLConnection conn = new URL(URL to send input stream").openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream outs = conn.getOutputStream();
outs.write(pdfBytes);
outs.flush();   
outs.close();
```

on other side get that input stream from request

```
request.getInputStream();
```

Comment: can you give me example pls ?

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = null;

                url = new URL("Your service URL");

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 0);
            connection.setUseCaches (false);
            DataOutputStream wr = null;

                wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());

            int code = 0;
            try {
                code = connection.getResponseCode();
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error occured while checking the CPR connection", e);
            }
            connection.disconnect();
```